# How do I start a second instance of a program from Unity's launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

It's all in the title.

Eg. if I have a gnome-terminal opened and I click on the gnome-terminal launcher icon, the running terminal will focus and no new instance will pop-up. Also, there is no item in the launcher icon's quicklist that would allow me to start a second instance of the program.

Comment: It would be simpler and more usable to keep the gnome bottom panel for opened program and the launcher just to run programs.

Comment: Terminal was just an example. What we need is a way to config to start another instance of any app from Unity Launcher.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You now can start a new instance via a middle clicking on the launcher icon.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be an alternative for those who don't have a middle mouse button (such as on my laptop's trackpad), such as by holding some combination of ctrl, alt or shift while clicking.

It is a convention in web browsers to use CTRL+click to mean the same as a middle-click.  I wish Unity did the same.  For now I have to right-click then select "New ______" from the context menu which is annoying.

Comment: If you have a trackpad is likely that you can obtain a middle-click by pressing the two mouse buttons at the same time.

Answer (score 11):

Click the launcher with the middle mousebutton.

Comment: If the program in question is gedit, then additionally you must right-click on the tab in gedit and "move to new window"

Answer (score 7):

At the moment, the only possibility to start a second instance, is using the Applications view, in the sidebar or the Ubuntulogo at the top.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a second Instance of the terminal you must select "New Terminal" in the File Menu from gnome-terminal. It's similar with Nautilus. But (currently) it's not possible to start more than one instance from the Launcher

Comment: I recently sent a suggestion to the Ayatana mailing list with a possible way to solve this situation: please check it at https://lists.launchpad.net/ayatana/msg04030.html or see the mockup here: http://imgur.com/1cP0B.png

Answer (score 2):

cntrl shift N opens a 2nd terminal where I have a terminal focused and cntrl D closes a termimal

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on it's running launcher icon and choose New Window.

Comment: Not all applications offer a possibility to launch a second instance via their quicklists.