# Launch a second copy of an application using unity

Tags: unity, launcher, multiple-instances

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I start a second instance of a program from Unity's launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11355/how-do-i-start-a-second-instance-of-a-program-from-unitys-launcher)

I figured out how to launch a second copy of an application using the keyboard, (Super+Shift+#) but this works only for the first ten launcher items. Is it possible using the launcher with a mouse?

Garvan

Answer (score 4):

Middle click.

Yeah it's not ideal. There should be a right-click option so people don't have to magically discover these things.