# How to Launch Multiple Processes from the dash?

Tags: unity-dash

Is there a way to configure the Ubuntu 12.04 menu/dash to launch multiple instances (processes) of an application?

With Vim, I sometimes like to launch several versions of it. With Vim configured on the toolbar, I am able to launch Vim once or quit Vim. If I click on the Vim icon with one Vim session running, I can only go back to the one Vim session.

Does such a configuration setting exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration way you may be looking for is creating a [Quicklist](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/LauncherAPI#Quicklists) for the Launcher to enable a second application instance from a mouse right click context menu. How this can be done is easily seen in the default `gnome-terminal.desktop` file below. Watch out for the last entries in `[Desktop Action New]`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminal
Comment=Use the command line
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
X-GNOME-DocPath=gnome-terminal/index.html
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-terminal
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=BugBuddyBugs
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.4.1.1
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Keywords=Run;
Actions=New
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-terminal

[Desktop Action New]
Name=New Terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
OnlyShowIn=Unity
```

There also still is the mouse (wheel) middle click option to run a new application instance as shown here:

- [How do I start a second instance of a program from Unity's launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11355/how-do-i-start-a-second-instance-of-a-program-from-unitys-launcher)

More on Launchers and Quicklists here:

- [What Custom Launchers and Unity Quicklists are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available)

Answer (score 1):

If you middle click the icon in the launcher, it opens a new session of that program.

Comment: I only have a two button mouse.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus you don't have a scroll wheel that is "clickable"? Just try and click that, if you have one.

Comment: Didn't realize the wheel is clickable. Thanks.