# multiple windows from launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, xterm

I use `xterm` as my default terminal emulator (mainly because I also use OSX and BSD, so having a cross-platform terminal emulator comes in handy). I have added an `xterm` icon to my Unity launcher, but it does not let me open multiple `xterm` windows, i.e. once one window is open, right-clicking on the icon again will not show the option of opening a new window. I know that I can open new windows from the command line, but it would be nice to be able to do so from the launcher, same as I would if I were using gnome-terminal (or any other application for that matter).

Is there a way to add the 'new window' option to the launcher for `xterm`?

Comment: Try [mouse middle click](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11355/how-do-i-start-a-second-instance-of-a-program-from-unitys-launcher) or you can also create an own [quicklist](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/what-custom-launchers-and-unity-quicklists-are-available) in case you made your custom Launcher entry.

Comment: brilliant! Mouse middle click worked, can you put this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's the default behaviour of the Launcher. As we already have a question/answer regarding this we should better link it to the "master" question - good you brought it up again this may help others too ;)